# How to create an interface based on specific requirements

Tags: java

I will try to explain this as best as I can since I'm not understanding the question 100% either.

I am asked to create an interface to build two requisites involving two concepts called Numerous Family and Inland Company. A Numerous Family is a family which has more than 4 sons and an Inland Company is a Company from an Inland region. The system should be able to manage the definition of the number of children, for the Numerous Families, and also keep a list that associates the Inland Regions to a value (this value doesn't really matter into the context, but needs to exist).

A method `public double taxReduction()` should be implemented by the Numerous Families and the Inland Regions which will calculate something later explained.

Now it's important to say that 2 Classes already exist called `Taxpayer` and `Company`, with some variables that I don't think matter for this question:

```
public class Taxpayer {
    ...
}
public class Company {
    ...
}
```

The Numerous Family concerns the Taxpayer and the Inland Regions concerns the Company. I don't understand much of interfaces but my idea was for each of the definitions:

1. Numerous Family - Create a variable `private int sons` with respective get's and set's with a method `public double taxReduction()` which returns a percentage of each son `if(this.sons>4)`, 0 otherwise (these values are still to define, but for the whole picture they don't really matter).
2. Inland Company - Create another Class called Region:

   ```
    public Class Region{ 
        private String name; 
        private boolean inland; //if it's an inland region
    }
   ```

   Add a variable `public Region region;` with get's and set's and with the same method taxReduction.

Now the questions are(if the above is right):

- How would my interface be written? Do I just add `double taxReduction;` to the Interface?
- How would I keep a list with the inland regions? Do I create a list on my main with all the inland regions or should I be initializing this somewhere else?

Observation: The method `taxReduction()` will be used to calculate some numbers, where I would need to check if I'm visiting an instance that represents a Numerous Family or an Inland Company. I don't really need to know how to check in which instance I'm at since I know how to do that, just how to really sort all this interface problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my two cents:

> How would my interface be written? Do i just add the double taxReduction; to the Interface?

Just create your interface with `double getTaxReduction()` method.

In your implementation of `TaxPayer` or `Company` you provide concrete body for it.

> How would i keep a list with the inland regions? Do i create a list on my main with all the inland regions or should i be initializing this somewhere else?

It really depends.

`Region` values is  a slow changing dimension (rarely updated).

You have to question yourself: Should the app go international (new Region added as new branch in a Country is opened) then the `Region` definitely should be stored inside DB where you can manage it dynamically.

If the `Region` values are somewhat fixed (used in a country, `Region` definitions rarely change), so the best place is an enum `Region`. If you want to modify it why running, you can pair it with a `properties` file and `ReloadableResource` like in Spring

Comment: So the variables creation in the body of the TaxPayer and Company are correct? About the Regions, they will be completely fixed. I'll have 2 types of files, one that will run a test of the app and another that will be the one to update, i.e., register new TaxPayer and other funcionalities. Both need to already contain all the Regions existant. They don't really need to be that much, just enough for now to be able to test it.

Comment: `So the variables creation in the body of the` Sorry but I didn't talk about any `variables`. My suggestion is to create the `method` in your interface, how you implement it is up to your decision :D